# How to call or pop up fragment upon button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, popup

I am implement an android app. I want to call or pop-up fragment upon  rating button click.

For example, Here I attached screenshot. When I click up on the rate button so how to call pop-up or fragment like this

[image]

[image]

Please help me how to call these fragment?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I didn't write the code. I am asking about that @IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to design another layout only for the pop up to be shown and make it alignparenttop. Here is the example layout

Create new xml file dialogue.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Fill in your design in this place"
            android:textSize="10dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Once you have created your design. You need to call it in your onbutton click. Following is the example to show a dialogue

```
ratingButton.setOnCLickListener(new view.OnCLickListener(){ 
    @Override 
    public void onCLick(View v){
         final Dialog fbDialogue = new Dialog(ProfileActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
            fbDialogue.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0)));
            fbDialogue.setContentView(R.layout.facebook_dialogue);
            fbDialogue.setCancelable(true);
            fbDialogue.show();
    } 
}); 


    Hey I have put the code in onclicklistener. Check it . The above code works perfectly fine for me. As per my requirement I wanted the dialogue on the bottom of the screen . I have just made few lines of code change above to meet your requirement. My requirement was something like this
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Anu, If I want to perform some activity up on dialogue so how can do that?

Comment: If I want to add button and text up on this dialogue so how to add it?

Comment: You can use a linearlayout and set its orientation as Vertical and start adding textViews and buttons in it.

Comment: Is it possible to add in RelativeLayout?? I already added on RelativeLayout but its not working. Textview and button is not showing.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this as an overlay over your current layout. It can vary from implementation to implementation.

I implemented this using the following approach:

```
<RelativeLayout>  <- This is the parent 

     <RelativeLayout id="actual_layout"> <- This is where you will implement the layout
           <!--Implement your layout here-->
     </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout id="rating_container"
      visibility="gone"
      background="#BB000000">  <- This is to set the translucent black background
           <RelativeLayout id="rating_dialog" 
            alignParnetTop="true"> <- This is the rating dialog
                    <!--Your implementation here-->
           </RelativeLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now toggle the "rating_container"'s visibility in onCLick of your "Rating" button.

```
ratingButton.setOnCLickListener(new view.OnCLickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCLick(View v){
         toggleRatingContainer(true);
    }
});
```

You can follow this approach to implement your requirement. Let me know if you need more help with this.

NOTE: I have not written the complete code. Also, I didn't check but directly typed everything.

**EDIT**:

You can implement the toggleRatingContainer like the following:

```
public void toggleRatingContainer(boolean showRatingDialog){
    ratingContainer.setVisibility((showRatingDialog)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
}
```

Here, "ratingContainer" is the "RelativeLayout" with the id "rating_container" which you can get in your activity's onCreate method.

And then you can toggle its visibility to "View.GONE" when the "Submit" or "Cancel" button is clicked by calling the same method passing "false" as the argument.

Comment: Hey @Wanted, here toggleRatingContainer() method showing the error Cann't resolve method toggleRatingContainer(boolean). so how to solve that??

Comment: Hey @Rajendra, I've edited the answer. I've given just the structure. Please treat the code I've written as the pseudo code as I've not written the complete code here. Actual implementation can vary based on your implementation. It is just one of the approaches that you can follow to implement your requirement. Let me know if you need more help with this. Happy coding!!

Comment: it is not working...When I clilcked upon the button so RelativeLayout showing below the main layout.